# Want to allow people to edit google calendar events, but only get 'See only free/busy' permission option

Tags: permissions, google-calendar-api

I've found this question asked several times when I've Googled for it, but the only solutions I can find relate to the old UI for Google Calendars and the options simply aren't in the new version.  It's a very simple problem I'm trying to solve, but I just can't see how to do it.

Basically, I've set up a 'family holidays' calendar in Google Calendars and I want to invite my family to add their holidays to it.  I've invited them on the 'Share this calendar' page under 'Share with specific people', but the only choice I have for their permissions in the drop-down list is: 'See only free/busy (hide details)'.

Can anyone tell me how to allow these invited people to be able to add new events and edit exiting events in this calendar as I just can't get the other options to show up?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out this is a Google Apps account.  I don't really understand how that differs from a normal Google account, but hey ho.  So I Googled to find the log-in to 'Google Apps'.  I logged in and it gave me access to more settings, one of which was master controls over permissions which seemed to override the calendar-level permissions on my family calendar.  I changed these master permissions, logged out and then back in, and I now have more permissions to allow people to edit this calendar.  Hooray!

Comment: Thanks for posting this on SO.  I've thought this was a bug in Google Calendar for ages.